# Hydration error on component's conditional rendering

Tags: next.js13

I'm getting a hydration issue, which I share in a screenshot below, on the following code and I've changed it a fair number of ways but I can't get any conclusion out of it.

I've tried different kinds of rendering the code conditionally, even separating into further components, but I can't really get to the bottom of it.

Am I missing some sort of guidelines here?

I'm using NextJS13 with Shadcn

```
"use client";

import {
  Dialog,
  DialogContent,
  DialogHeader,
  DialogTitle,
  DialogDescription,
  DialogFooter,
} from "@/components/ui/dialog";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import { Label } from "@/components/ui/label";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import URLInput from "@/components/url-input";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useEditBookmark } from "@/hooks/use-edit-bookmark";
import { useBookmark } from "@/hooks/use-get-bookmark";

export default function BookmarkEdit({
  params: { bookmarkId },
}: {
  params: { bookmarkId: string };
}) {
  const { bookmark, isLoading, isFetching, error } = useBookmark(
    parseInt(bookmarkId)
  );
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [url, setURL] = useState("");
  const [labels, setLabels] = useState("");

  const { edit } = useEditBookmark();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (bookmark) {
      setName(bookmark.name);
      setURL(bookmark.url);
      setLabels(bookmark.labels.join(","));
    }
  }, [bookmark]);

  if (isLoading || isFetching) {
    return (
      <Dialog open={true}>
        <DialogContent className="w-full flex items-center">
          <div
            className="inline-block h-6 w-6 animate-spin rounded-full border-4 border-solid border-current border-r-transparent align-[-0.125em] motion-reduce:animate-[spin_1.5s_linear_infinite]"
            role="status"
          ></div>
          <span className="ml-2">Loading...</span>
        </DialogContent>
      </Dialog>
    );
  }

  if (!bookmark) {
    return (
      <Dialog open={true}>
        <DialogContent className="w-full">
          <span className="ml-2">Bookmark not found</span>
        </DialogContent>
      </Dialog>
    );
  }

  const handleEditBookmark = async ({
    name,
    url,
    labels,
  }: {
    name: string;
    url: string;
    labels: string;
  }) => {
    edit({
      id: bookmark.id,
      name,
      url,
      labels: labels.split(",").map((label) => label.trim()),
    });
  };

  return (
    <Dialog open={true}>
      <DialogContent className="w-full">
        <DialogHeader>
          <DialogTitle>Add Bookmark</DialogTitle>
          <DialogDescription>
            The only required field is actually the URL
          </DialogDescription>
        </DialogHeader>
        <div className="grid gap-4 py-4">
          <URLInput url={url} setURL={setURL} setLabels={setLabels} />
          <div className="grid grid-cols-4 items-center gap-4">
            <Label htmlFor="name" className="text-right">
              Name
            </Label>
            <Input
              id="name"
              placeholder="Something..."
              className="col-span-3"
              onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
              value={name}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="grid grid-cols-4 items-center gap-4">
            <Label htmlFor="labels" className="text-right">
              Labels
            </Label>
            <Input
              id="labels"
              placeholder="work,product"
              className="col-span-3"
              onChange={(e) => setLabels(e.target.value)}
              value={labels}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <DialogFooter>
          <Button onClick={() => handleEditBookmark({ name, url, labels })}>
            Edit bookmark
          </Button>
        </DialogFooter>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is this error only in the console or is it on a popup prevent this app from running. Does it always occur?

Comment: It's just in the console, it doesn't prevent anything. As far as I've read in some rare cases you can simply suppress it, but I find it odd. It might be tied to shadcn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that Schadcn or another dependency related to it is outdated. Try running this command `npm update`.

If this doesn't work there is nothing you can do to fix. This because the issue is with Radix UI the underlying primitive for Schadcn UI. In this case all you can do is suppress the error like so:

```
"use client";

import {
  Dialog,
  DialogContent,
  DialogHeader,
  DialogTitle,
  DialogDescription,
  DialogFooter,
} from "@/components/ui/dialog";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import { Label } from "@/components/ui/label";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import URLInput from "@/components/url-input";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useEditBookmark } from "@/hooks/use-edit-bookmark";
import { useBookmark } from "@/hooks/use-get-bookmark";

export default function BookmarkEdit({
  params: { bookmarkId },
}: {
  params: { bookmarkId: string };
}) {
  const { bookmark, isLoading, isFetching, error } = useBookmark(
    parseInt(bookmarkId)
  );
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [url, setURL] = useState("");
  const [labels, setLabels] = useState("");

  const { edit } = useEditBookmark();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (bookmark) {
      setName(bookmark.name);
      setURL(bookmark.url);
      setLabels(bookmark.labels.join(","));
    }
  }, [bookmark]);

  if (isLoading || isFetching) {
    return (
      <Dialog open={true}>
        <DialogContent className="w-full flex items-center">
          <div
            className="inline-block h-6 w-6 animate-spin rounded-full border-4 border-solid border-current border-r-transparent align-[-0.125em] motion-reduce:animate-[spin_1.5s_linear_infinite]"
            role="status"
          ></div>
          <span className="ml-2">Loading...</span>
        </DialogContent>
      </Dialog>
    );
  }

  if (!bookmark) {
    return (
      <Dialog open={true}>
        <DialogContent className="w-full">
          <span className="ml-2">Bookmark not found</span>
        </DialogContent>
      </Dialog>
    );
  }

  const handleEditBookmark = async ({
    name,
    url,
    labels,
  }: {
    name: string;
    url: string;
    labels: string;
  }) => {
    edit({
      id: bookmark.id,
      name,
      url,
      labels: labels.split(",").map((label) => label.trim()),
    });
  };

  return (
    <Dialog open={true} suppressHydrationWarning={true}>
      <DialogContent className="w-full">
        <DialogHeader>
          <DialogTitle>Add Bookmark</DialogTitle>
          <DialogDescription>
            The only required field is actually the URL
          </DialogDescription>
        </DialogHeader>
        <div className="grid gap-4 py-4">
          <URLInput url={url} setURL={setURL} setLabels={setLabels} />
          <div className="grid grid-cols-4 items-center gap-4">
            <Label htmlFor="name" className="text-right">
              Name
            </Label>
            <Input
              id="name"
              placeholder="Something..."
              className="col-span-3"
              onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
              value={name}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="grid grid-cols-4 items-center gap-4">
            <Label htmlFor="labels" className="text-right">
              Labels
            </Label>
            <Input
              id="labels"
              placeholder="work,product"
              className="col-span-3"
              onChange={(e) => setLabels(e.target.value)}
              value={labels}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <DialogFooter>
          <Button onClick={() => handleEditBookmark({ name, url, labels })}>
            Edit bookmark
          </Button>
        </DialogFooter>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
}
```

Comment: I'll take it as the answer, unfortunately it doesn't quite tell me where the issue is but I understand it can be hard to get to the source.